# How to count distinct from two sets of tables

Tags: mysql

I have two sets of tables one set is called successful and the other is unsuccessful which I have done a union, I would like to be able to do a distinct count on players name. Both set have the same column names.

```
SELECT
  s.date,
  s.location,
  sn.name
FROM
  s_location s
  INNER JOIN s_players sp ON sp.p_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN s_name sn ON sn.id = sp.p_id
WHERE
  s.date BETWEEN '2018-11-16' AND '2018-11-16'
UNION
SELECT
  u.date,
  u.location,
  un.name
FROM
  u_location u
  INNER JOIN u_players up ON up.p_id = u.id
  INNER JOIN u_name un ON un.id = up.p_id
WHERE
    u.date BETWEEN '2018-11-16' AND '2018-11-16'
ORDER BY
  location
```

Successful Tables
Location table s_location

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| id        | location | date       |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 10        | LOCA     | 2018-11-18 |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Players table s_players

```
+-----------+----------+
| LOC_id    | p_id     |
+-----------+----------+
| 10        | 667      |
| 10        | 104      |
| 10        | 733      | 
+-----------+----------+
```

Players names table s_name

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | name     |
+-----------+----------+
| 667       | John     |
| 104       | Peter    |
| 733       | Mary     |
+-----------+----------+
```

Unsuccessful Tables
Location table u_location

```
+-----------+----------+------------+
| id        | location | date       |
+-----------+----------+------------+
| 11        | LOCB     | 2018-11-18 |
+-----------+----------+------------+
```

Players table u_players

```
+-----------+----------+
| LOC_id    | p_id     |
+-----------+----------+
| 11        | 667      |
| 11        | 114      |
| 11        | 243      | 
+-----------+----------+
```

Players names table u_name

```
+-----------+----------+
| id        | name     |
+-----------+----------+
| 667       | John     |
| 114       | Sally    |
| 733       | James    |
+-----------+----------+
```

RESULTS TABLE from both sets

```
+------------+----------+------------+
| date       | location | name       |
+------------+----------+------------+
| 2018-11-18 | LOCA     | John       |
| 2018-11-18 | LOCA     | Peter      |
| 2018-11-18 | LOCA     | Mary       |
| 2018-11-18 | LOCB     | John       |
| 2018-11-18 | LOCB     | Sally      |
| 2018-11-18 | LOCB     | James      |
+------------+----------+------------+
```

How do I do a distinct count on name so I get 5 (As John (p_id 667) is in both set of tables (successful and unsuccessful))

The results that I'm after is

```
+------------+------------+
| date       | name       |
+------------+------------+
| 2018-11-18 | John       |
| 2018-11-18 | Peter      |
| 2018-11-18 | Mary       |
| 2018-11-18 | Sally      |
| 2018-11-18 | James      |
+------------+------------+
```

Comment: How does the expected result table should look like? If you want to eliminate name duplicates, then how does the different locations should be in the final table?

Comment: I just want to eliminate the duplicate names, which ones doesn't matter as all i want is the number of different "names" participants, the result should be, John, Peter, Mary, Sally, James. 5 individuals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the above query with another select having distinct on column `name` and `date`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.date, t.name
FROM (
    SELECT
      s.date,
      s.location,
      sn.name AS name
    FROM
      s_location s
      INNER JOIN s_players sp ON sp.p_id = s.id
      INNER JOIN s_name sn ON sn.id = sp.p_id
    WHERE
      s.date BETWEEN '2018-11-16' AND '2018-11-16'
    UNION
    SELECT
      u.date,
      u.location,
      un.name AS name
    FROM
      u_location u
      INNER JOIN u_players up ON up.p_id = u.id
      INNER JOIN u_name un ON un.id = up.p_id
    WHERE
        u.date BETWEEN '2018-11-16' AND '2018-11-16'
    ORDER BY
      location
) t
```